# How to make a list of odd numbers using range and without if statement

Tags: python

I am trying to learn Python with Eric Matthes's Python Crash Course. In one section of "Try it yourself" I have the next task.

> Use the third argument of the `range()` function to make a list of the odd numbers from `1` to `20`. Us a `for` loop to print each number.

I tried:

```
odd_numbers = []
for value in range(1,11):
    number = value % 2 = 1
    odd_numbers.append(number)
print(odd_numbers)
```

This does not work.
Any way I can solve this without an if statement?

Comment: Yes, as the task tells you, use the __third argument__ of the range function.

Comment: The instructions say to use the _third_ argument of [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range). The third argument takes a `step` argument - you're still calling `range()` with two arguments.

Answer (score 2):

```
for value in range(1,20,2):
    print(value)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do exactly as it says.

The range function takes three arguments: `range([start], end, [step])`

To get even numbers, start at an even number like 0, and step at 2.

`range(0,end,2)`

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(1, 11, 2):
    print ('This will print only odd numbers:', i)
```

The output:

```
This will print only odd numbers: 1
This will print only odd numbers: 3
This will print only odd numbers: 5
This will print only odd numbers: 7
This will print only odd numbers: 9
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#this is will create a list of odd numbers 1-20   
#create an empty list
odd = []
#create a for loop with range count by 2 & then append to the list
for numbers in range(1, 21, 2):
    odd.append(numbers)
print(odd)

#To create a list and only print the odd numbers 1-20
odd = list(range(1,21,2))
for number in odd:
    print(number)
```